# How to write isilo .pdb files in C#?

Tags: c#

I would like to write my own .pdb isilo files to read in my iphone with the isilo application but i don't have an editor or something like that. So Im stuck because I dont have the API to write that kind of files. C# or Visual basic .net is ok.
Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

Just write normal .HTML files and use [iSiloX](http://www.isilox.com/) to convert a collection of such files to a .PDB file.

There's even a command line converter, iSiloXC, to use if you want to batch-execute an iSiloX project.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped me. Now I can write my own PDB without work.